# BigQuery: counting entries between 30-minute timestamp intervals

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have a pre-created table `data`:

```
id      timestamp_entry
1       "2023-01-01 04:11:24 UTC"
2       "2023-01-01 04:14:55 UTC"
...
99999   "2023-01-31 23:45:59 UTC"
```

where `timestamp_entry` has a uniform time zone "UTC" and ranges within January 2023.

I want to create a 30-minute time skeleton and count how many entries in `timestamp_entry` falls into each interval.

I first created a subquery:

```
WITH
intervals AS(
  SELECT interval AS start_time,
         TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_ADD(interval, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE), INTERVAL 1 SECOND) AS end_time
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY("2023-01-01 00:00:00 UTC", "2023-01-31 23:59:59 UTC", INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)) interval
)
```

But ideally, I want my outcome to show:

```
start_time                  end_time                    count
"2023-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"   "2023-01-01 00:29:59 UTC"   0
"2023-01-01 00:30:00 UTC"   "2023-01-01 00:59:59 UTC"   0
...
"2023-01-31 23:00:00 UTC"   "2023-01-31 23:29:59 UTC"   12
"2023-01-31 23:30:00 UTC"   "2023-01-31 23:59:59 UTC"   5
```

where `count` shows how many `timestamp_entry` from `data` falls into each interval.

I have tried using `RIGHT JOIN` with `BETWEEN`, but I won't be able to join the two tables as there are no exact "matches".

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider below as well

```sql
WITH data AS (
  -- put your data here
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(slot) start_time,
       TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(slot + 1800 - 1) end_time,
       COUNT(timestamp_entry) `count`
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1672531200, 1675207800, 1800)) slot
  LEFT JOIN data ON DIV(slot, 1800) = DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp_entry), 1800)
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

- `1672531200` -> UNIX_SECONDS("2023-01-01 00:00:00 UTC");
- `1675207800` -> UNIX_SECONDS("2023-01-31 23:30:00 UTC");

Answer (score 0):

Works exactly with `JOIN` and `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT start_time, end_time, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM data
  LEFT JOIN intervals
    ON timestamp_entry >= start_time
   AND timestamp_entry <  end_time
 GROUP BY start_time, end_time
 ORDER BY start_time
```